# Match heatmap coordinates with jpeg coordinates in R

Tags: r, cloud, jpeg, heatmap

I have a question about heatmaps in R. I would like to create a heatmap that matches the length and width of a jpeg. I used the following code:

```
d <- structure(list(X = c(1383L, 1452L, 1226L, 1057L, 1056L, 1240L), Y = c(682L, 616L, 440L, 424L, 372L, 386L)), .Names = c("X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,1057L))

require(MASS)

dens <- kde2d(d$X, d$Y, h=100, n=14)

filled.contour(dens)
```

And, as I am new to R, I actually do not understand what the h and n stand for, so an explanation of what those do would be helpful..

Anyways, I was able to generate a heatmap, that accurately showed that more interactions were happening in one spot than another spot. But my heatmap and jpeg do not line up.

Here is the picture of the heatmap: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B75PBZeWiCeJbld0Z2xobHh0SUE/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the picture of my clicks that I want to relate in the heatmap:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B75PBZeWiCeJZWtsM0Q2cXVIODQ/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, the blobs on the heatmap don't really reflect where my clicks are on the jpeg..

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> And, as I am new to R, I actually do not understand what the h and n stand for, so an explanation of what those do would be helpful..

You can get the documentaiton on any function by preceding it with a question mark, like `?kde2d`. If you try that command, you'll see the following in the documentation:

> h - vector of bandwidths for x and y directions. Defaults to normal reference bandwidth (see bandwidth.nrd). A scalar value will be taken to apply to both directions.
>
> n - Number of grid points in each direction. Can be scalar or a length-2 integer vector.

Regarding the length and width of the heatmap, I'm a little confused as to what you're specific problem is, but you can export your image using the `jpeg` command, which takes `height` and `width` as inputs. So if you know the height and width of the jpeg you're trying to match this heatmap too, you can just specify the height and width of your jpeg output.